# specifying arguments to an Objective-C commandline app

Tags: objective-c, command-line-arguments

I had made an Objective-C command line app which takes a string entered by the user.
Currently I created it in such a way that it asks user at command prompt

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        printf("Enter your string: ");
        char str[11];
        scanf("%s", str);
        printf("Your string is %s\n", str);
        NSString *lastName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:str];

        NSLog(@"lastName=%@", lastName);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So when I run this program from terminal by typing `programName`, I will get the following:

`Enter your string:`

instead I would like to type something like this on terminal `programName StringThatNeedsToBeneterd` and it should give the same out put.

Comment: Wait, so you want the "Enter your string:" to be another string, that is specified as a parameter?

Comment: I can give an example. If you take ffmpeg, it requires some arguments which it will use. Similarly i need to supply a string as an argument while running the ./program which(the string argument) gets printed instead of getting a prompt asking me to enter the string.

Comment: Well, I can't really ask that question, because I am completely unfamiliar with C/objective-C, but try replacing "printf("Enter your string: ");" with "printf(argv + ": ");

Comment: This is a basic C question. Command line args are passed as parameters to `main`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575801/objective-c-main-routine-what-is-int-argc-const-char-argv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `argc` and `argv` arguments. They provide access to the command line arguments. Many introductions to C will describe how they work.

But, since you're using Objective-C and the Foundation framework, you can use [the `arguments` property of `NSProcessInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsprocessinfo?language=objc):

```
NSLog(@"arguments: %@", NSProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments);

// NSProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments[0] is the executable's name.

if (NSProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments.count > 1) {
    NSString *lastName = NSProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments[1];
}
```

This is nicer than using `argc` and `argv` because you get to use the Foundation types `NSArray` and `NSString`.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I unfortunately stopped coding in objective-C a few years ago.  I am not sure if this works or not.