# sys.argv equivalent in Objective-C

Tags: python, objective-c

As usual, I use `sys.argv[1]` to get the first argument after the name of the executable file in Python, but now I'm coding a program in Objective-C. My question is what would be the equivalent of `sys.argv[1]` in Objective-C? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_command_line_arguments.htm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Objective-c main routine, what is: int argc, const char \* argv\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575801/objective-c-main-routine-what-is-int-argc-const-char-argv)

Comment: thanks y'all I managed to solve this problem